# Java String parsing and playback through MIDI Synthesizer error

Tags: java, string, char, midi, synthesizer

I'm trying to implement a morse playback mechanism in Java. I had it working fine with a String, but in order to implement a stop function, I am trying to have it work with a single char, which would be delivered one at a time from the driver.

However, the program seems to somewhat randomly cease playback. For instance:

"Hello": ... . .-.. .-.. ---

Goes silent just before the "---"

"hhhh": .... .... .... ....

Goes silent after the first dot of the fourth h.

"ooooo" : --- --- --- --- ---

Goes silent after the fourth o.

Driver:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      Morse.play(returnval);
      /*
      char[] c = returnval.toCharArray();
      for (char v : c){
        String s = "";
        s += v;
        System.out.print(s);
        Morse.play(s);
      }
        */
  }
};

new Thread(r).start();
```

Playback method:

```
public static void play(String morse){
    char[] notes = morse.toCharArray();
    int unit = 100;
    int mult = 0;

    try {
        Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synthesizer.open();

        MidiChannel channel = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];
        channel.programChange(0, 80);
        for (char note : notes) {
            switch (note){
            case '.':
                mult = 1;
                break;
            case '-':
                mult = 3;
                break;
            case ' ':
                mult = -3;
                break;
            default:
                mult = 0;
                break;
            }
            try{
                if (mult > 0){
                    channel.noteOn(60, 30);
                    Thread.sleep(mult*unit);
                }

                else {
                    Thread.sleep(mult*-1*unit);
                }

                channel.allNotesOff();
                Thread.sleep(100);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but for me it's working fine in all cases. Can you write a set of Strings for which this is not working for you as per expectation?

Comment: By the way, I recommend to not program the Synthesizer timing with Thread.sleep(). Thread.sleep() is not guaranteed to return immediately after the sleep time elapsed. Instead, you could connect a `Sequencer` to your `Synthesizer` and program notes in a `Track`. There will be much less timing glitches then.

Comment: I think my previous description of error cases was wrong. Updated. And the other Thread controls UI. And thanks, I'll look into the `Sequencer`.

Comment: The thirteenth non-whitespace character maybe? I know thirteen is obviously an unlucky number,but Java shouldn't know that.

Comment: Can you try adding another sleep *after* the loop? Maybe your Java Synthesizer is slow and plays sounds with a small delay sufficient enough to eat the last notes you were about to play. Maybe replacing the `channel.allNotesOff();` with a `channel.noteOff(60, 30);` could also improve the situation.

Comment: No improvement, with either sleep(20) or 200.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65472/discussion-between-christian-hujer-and-user1710742).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code looks all okay and should work. However, there can be glitches due to `Synthesizer` being too slow and the selected instrument having a decay. I could improve the results on my end by introducing an additional delay of 1000ms at the end after playing the Morse code sequence, so that the Thread would not stop yet and the Midi resources would not be closed / reclaimed too early. The required delay might depend on the system and the chosen instrument.